# integration application with facebook

Tags: facebook, spring, authentication, spring-social

Is is possible use Spring Social to authentication via Facebook ? 
Suppose I have a web application and want to log in there using your Facebook account. Can someone show me an example of how to do it ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to use [Spring Social Facebook](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/) connector. You can checkout, build and play with showcase app:

1. [showcase](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase) app that use java config
2. or the same [showcase](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-xml) if you prefer XML config. This version use new social namespace tags from 1.1.0.M1. They will be not available if you want use 1.0.2.RELEASE. It will be easy to fix (check out some older version of the app or just compare the source with 1.0.2 documentation, there are some minor differences)

Comment: I found solution in parallel to your response :) , anyway thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

From SpringSource's [Github Repository](https://github.com/SpringSource)

- [Greenhouse](https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse)
- [Spring Social Samples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples)